# WPF: Cannot set Visibility or call Show, after a Window has closed. Trying to open a main window after Splash

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Need to open a main window after splash screen has been closed after loading all application data.

It's giving error

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    DispatcherHelper.Initialize();

    Global = new AARFID.KeyManagement.UI.Properties.Settings();

    Splash splash = new Splash();
    var isClosed = splash.ShowDialog();
    if (isClosed == true)
    {
        splash.Close();
    }

    UI.Main m = new UI.Main();
    m.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this using `Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;`

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    DispatcherHelper.Initialize();

    Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;

    Global = new Properties.Settings();

    Splash splash = new Splash();
    var isClosed = splash.ShowDialog();

    Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;

    if (isClosed == true)
    {
        var main = new UI.Main();
        this.MainWindow = main;
        this.MainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer opening splash screen in different thread.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{        
    public Form1()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SplashStart));
        t.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1500);
        InitializeComponent();
        t.Abort();
        Form1.Activate(); 
    }        
    public void SplashStart()
    {
        Application.Run(new SplashScreen());
    }
}
}
```

Its a working code for me. You can try this as solution.